# How to upload a file to onedrive as a specific user?

Tags: python, api, onedrive

I am trying to upload files to a user OneDrive as that user.
I successfully registered my app and granted the correct permissions.
I am able to upload files to a user drive but only as application and not as the user.

I was able to do the same on google drive using google sdk which allow user impersonation.

I could not find any decent documentation on user impersonation for OneDrive.

```
import requests

params = {
    'grant_type':'client_credentials',
    'client_id': 'xxx',
    'client_secret': 'yyy',
    'resource':'https://graph.microsoft.com'
}

r = requests.post('https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/token', data=params, verify=False)
token = r.json()['access_token']

headers = {
    'Authorization':token
}

fileHandle = open('somefile.txt', 'rb')
r = requests.put('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/drive/items/root:/somefile.txt:/content',
                 headers=headers, data=fileHandle, verify=False)
fileHandle.close()
```

this is part of the response I get showing the file was created/modified by my application which make sense:

```
'createdBy': {
        'application': {
            'id': 'xxx',
            'displayName': 'my_app'
        }
    },
    'lastModifiedBy': {
        'application': {
            'id': 'xxx',
            'displayName': 'my_app'
        }
    },
```

my goal is to have my app impersonate my users to create/modify the files.

Is this even supported with onedrive api?